# Sequence from the last page \includepdf

Tags: pdfpages

How to specify the nth (e.g. 3rd) from the last page of a document `\includepdf[pages=<nth from the last page>]{<document>}`.

E.g. Specifically targeting page 8 only, if the pdf is 10 pages long but where the length of pdf is unknown, so cant just state `page=8`.

I read the docs and there is an option for `pages=last` but no specification on where to go from the last page.

Example from python indexing would be `pages[-3]`. But it seems the minus sign has a different function here.

Most of the questions I searched mostly returned `\AtEndDocument{}`, which has a different function as well.

Comment: Sorry again. I have edited the misleading term in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing *n* pages up to the last is not supported directly, but it can be done.

### File `wds1.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

### File `wds2.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fromlast}[1]{%
  \noexpand\the\numexpr\noexpand\AM@pagecount-#1+1\relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=\fromlast{4}-last]{wds1}

\end{document}
```

This prints just four pages, from 6 to 9, because `wds1.pdf` has nine pages.

[image]

Comment: Sorry. You are right in that regard. But my wording 'nth to last' might have been misleading. I meant 'nth from the last page' which is stated in the title of the question.

Comment: @WDS Sorry for the misunderstanding, now it should be as you wanted.